# ssh PubkeyAuthentication doesn't work for users other than root

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sshd

I have a problem to ssh to a machine with the user mw without a password.

I've used ssh-copy-id mw@machine.

I've looked in many places and googled a lot but still couldn't find the answer.

#### Some info:

- The `/home/mw` permissions: 

  `drwx------. 3 mw      mw      109 Oct 18 09:29 mw`
- The `/home/mw/.ssh` permissions: 

  `drwx------. 2 mw   root  61 Oct 18 09:23 .ssh`
- The `/home/mw/.ssh` directory files permissions: 

  `-rw-------. 1 mw mw    744 Oct 18 09:23 authorized_keys
  -rw-------. 1 mw root 1702 Oct 17 17:48 id_rsa
  -rw-------. 1 mw root  406 Oct 17 17:48 id_rsa.pub`

#### Some sshd configurations:

- `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PubkeyAuthentication` gives: `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
- `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep AuthorizedKeysFile` gives: `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`
- The `/home/mw/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains the correct public key of my local machine from which I try to `ssh`

#### Other usefull info:

- `ssh root@machine` works but `ssh mw@machine` doesn't work without a password
- If I run with root on the machine `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 2222` and then run `ssh -p 2222 mw@machine` on my laptop it works without a password

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You could increase the `LogLevel` on the server (in `sshd_config`), and see if sshd gives any explanation on why public key auth failed.

Comment: Is the mw user's home directory stored on a shared filesystem which is mounted from another server? Or an encrypted filesystem?

Comment: Is the `/home/mw/.ssh` directory above the local or the remote? If it is the remote one, it shouldn't have the private key and if it is the local one, what are the permissions on the directory and files on the remote? Also the "root" group could be  a problem.

Comment: @xenoid it is over remote machine, it has private so the machine could ssh to other machines as well. The permissions which I've shown are the remote machine permissions not my local. I figure since it works with other users there is no problem with m local permissions

Comment: @sborsky I set the `LogLevel VERBOSE` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and did a `tail -f` on `/var/log/secure`. The result was: when I tried to connect and it asked me for a password nothing was logged, if I canceled the connection request there was a new line of log `Connection closed by ***** port **** [preauth]` as expected.

Comment: @SlavaShpitalny there could be a problem with the permission for that private key on your local.

Comment: @xenoid when I ssh to that same machine as `root` it works without a password. The issue is with the `mw` user

Comment: After setting the `LogLevel DEBUG` it yells at me with: `Could not open authorized keys '/home/mw/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`.

Comment: Fixed it with the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688844/sshd-gives-error-could-not-open-authorized-keys-although-permissions-seem-corre basically I ran `restorecon -FRvv ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to run `restorecon -FRvv ~/.ssh` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688844/sshd-gives-error-could-not-open-authorized-keys-although-permissions-seem-corre